# How to make a transition between 2 strips in NLA Editor?

Tags: nla-editor

In the NLA Editor, I set two strip actions, each one of these actions defined with the dope sheet.

However, I have a gap (20 frames about) between these 2 strips in NLA.

Do you know how to interpolate easily between these 2 strips, without defining other action which could be called for example "Transition action"?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Actually you CAN add a transition to fill a gap.

[image: Actually you can add a transition to fill a gap.]

I wish it could be non-linearly interpolated, though.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can't add a transition to fill a gap.

If you want to interpolate 2 strips they have to overlap, therefore you have to change the speed of your action or add more "action" to your strips.

### Speed

- Select the strip
- In the Properties Panel (<kbd>P</kbd>) > Action Clip, increase the **Scale** value of *Playback Settings*

### Extrapolation

To extend a strip, you could set the channel extrapolation mode to *Linear Extrapolation* (or some loop) first, then increase the End Frame in the Action Clip Panel.

**EDIT**
Using this method, however, the last frame will be determinate by the generated curve and it could produce odd results (note the rotation of the cube at the end of the animation).

If you cannot scale the strip or re-arrange the strips, I suggest you to "fill the gap" editing (or adding) the actions keyframes

[image: NLA interpolation]

Comment: All right, that is what I thought.